# Opinions on base malt: Prairie Malt from Biggar, Sask.

Tags: beer, flavor, malt, base-malt

I'm wondering if any of you have any opinions on a base malt called "Prairie Malt", made by [Prairie Malt Limited](http://www.prairiemaltltd.com/) of Biggar, Saskatchewan (Canada).

There's something in the flavor of some of my beers that I don't quite like, and it seems like the only thing these particular batches have in common is this base malt.

Do any of you have experience, good or bad, with this malt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prairie Malt is a fairly standard 2-row, and should not add too much flavor. While I've never tried it myself, you can totally try eating, or sucking on a few of the raw kernels, and see if you can identify the flavor that's bothering you. If it's not that, maybe describe the off-flavor in more detail? It could still be part of your process (equipment issues, temperatures, etc.)

Comment: The raw kernels taste great.  I love 'em.  Nice nutty flavor.